# Lengths of the shortest "simple" equation, that use only the number '1', equal to a given natural numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a formula, for determining the length of the shortest formula, that uses only the number '**1**', **parenthesis**, and the hyper**operations** $\{\{+, - \}, \{\times, / \}, \{\text{^}, \log_N,\text{nth root}\}, \{↑↑,\ldots\}, \ldots \}$ , that is equal to a **given natural number?**

The trend is simple at first, before gradually becoming very complex, below is a list of what I think should be the first few (first 400) elements, followed by a list of their lengths.

$$\small{1\\1+1\\1+1+1\\1+1+1+1\\1+1+1+1+1\\1+1+1+1+1+1\\1+1+1+1+1+1+1\\(1+1)\text{^}(1+1+1)\\(1+1+1)\text{^}(1+1)\\(1+1+1)\text{^}(1+1)+1\\(1+1+1)\text{^}(1+1)+1+1\\(1+1+1+1)\times(1+1+1)\\(1+1+1+1)\times(1+1+1)+1\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)-1-1\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)-1\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)+1\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)+1+1\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)+1+1+1\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)+1+1+1+1\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)+1+1+1+1+1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)-1-1-1-1-1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)-1-1-1-1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)-1-1-1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)-1-1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)-1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)+1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)+1+1\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)+1+1+1\\(1+1)\text{^}(1+1+1+1+1)-1\\(1+1)\text{^}(1+1+1+1+1)\\\ldots\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)\times(1+1)\\\ldots\\(1+1)\text{^}(1+1+1+1+1+1)\\\ldots\\(1+1+1)\text{^}(1+1+1+1)\\\ldots\\(1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)\times(1+1+1+1)\\\ldots\\(1+1+1+1+1)\text{^}(1+1+1)\\(1+1+1+1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)+1\\(1+1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)/(1+1)-1\\(1+1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)/(1+1)\\\ldots\\(1+1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)\\\ldots\\(1+1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)*(1+1+1)/(1+1)\\(1+1)↑↑(1+1+1)\times(1+1+1+1+1)\text{^}(1+1)\\\ \\1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 19, 17, 15, 13\\15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 23, 21, 19, 17, 15, 13, 15, 17, 19, 19, 17\\\ldots}$$

---

In answer to, Elaqqad, if so restrict operations to the **first few**, perhaps with some info about why this is necessary.

---

Thanks to Ross Millikan for showing that with just '**1**', **parenthesis**, $+$ and $\times$, the answer is the sequence at [oeis.org/A005245](http://oeis.org/A005245), and additionally with **powers** is [oeis.org/A025280](http://oeis.org/A025280).

Thease sequences decelerate fantastically :)

Thease sequences take only the number of $1$s into account and ignore factors such as parenthesis complexity. From the $2$nd sequence, numbers that are more complicated to construct than any smaller number include:

$1, 2, 3, 4,\\5, 7, 11, 13, 21, 23, \ldots$

Of which are not prime:

$4, 21, \ldots$

---

From my sequences above:

Numbers that are more complicated to construct than any smaller number include:

$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,\\7, 10, 11, 13, 20, 21, \ldots$

Of which are not prime:

$4, 6, 10, 20, 21\ldots$

The table below shows the first appearance of operations, although the larger values may yet prove inaccurate:

$+\ 2\\-\ 14\\\times\ 12\\/\ 384\\\text{^}\ 9\\↑↑\ 16$

Comment: Do mean $N$ in $log_N$ to be arbitary, or does it also have to be constructed in terms of $1$'s?

Comment: First of all you have to specify all the operations we can use, and it would be traceable if you restrict the operations to a finite set, otherwise this would be a problem of Kolmogorov complexity studied in theoretical computer science!

Comment: $9=(1+1+1)\text{^}(1+1)$, 13 characters not 17. Obviously 10 can then be constructed with only 15.

Comment: Constructed in terms of 1s. As with 2*3, 3*2, 2/3, 3/2, their is 2^3, 3^2, Log(2, 3) and Log(3, 2).

Comment: Also 8 = (1+1)^(1+1+1)

Comment: But surely the answer is no, there is no closed-form formula for this.

Comment: You might be interested in http://oeis.org/A005245, which is the minimum number of $1$'s  to which you can add +*() and get each number.  It is up the same alley.  I didn't find your sequence in OEIS

Comment: As an old HP calculator fan, how about an RPL version: numbers are put on the stack, + and * are immediately performed, and, maybe, add the swap operator. Of course, no nasty parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar is [OEIS A005245](http://oeis.org/A005245), which gives the number of $1$'s required to represent each number using just add, multiply, and parentheses.  Subtraction, division, and powers are not allowed and the other characters are not counted.  For example, $19=(1+1)\times (1+1+1)\times (1+1+1)+1$ uses nine $1$'s.  Allowing powers gets [A025280](http://oeis.org/A025280)

Comment: Sorry, I think my suggested edit may have conflicted with you adding the info about the other series.

Comment: @alan2here:  It did, but no problem.  I incorporated your suggestions.